# Can I drill a metal plate next to my window?

Tags: walls, studs, metal

[image: picture1][image: picture2]I hit metal while drilling a hole next to a window. The identical house next to mine is at the pre-drywall stage, so I took a picture of the window area. I suspect the thing I'm hitting is called a stud plate tie. My questions are:

1. Is this correct?
2. Is it safe to drill through it?

Comment: You need to make sure it is a tie and not a protective plate for electric/plumbing.  Drilling into a tie is okay, drilling into a protection plate is bad.

Comment: Updated my post. For some reason pictures didn't attach

Comment: @crip659 I thought it would be very odd to place something electrical or plumbing related so close to a window

Comment: Me too, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: Great idea checking out the house next door while you have the chance.  It could be convenient in the future to have clear photos of all the internal walls, assuming your homes have the same plan and are built by the same builders.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the picture, that's a strap -- fancy people would call it a stud plate tie ;) -- and it's no problem to drill through it.

Comment: OK if it's not a large hole

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's o.k. to drill through it, with a smallish hole. You might even be lucky and happen to drill straight through an existing hole - there are plenty of them!

But consider moving the bracket a little to one side, that way, you're straight into wood, making life much easier.